# Should I use a POST request on /resources/ or PUT request on /resources/id/ to create a new object?

Tags: rest

What's the RESTful way to create an object?
Should I use POST on the /resources/ URI and return the URI to the newly created resource in the response or should I use PUT on the /resources/id/ URI?
A GET request for /resources/id/ would surely return a 404 but should PUT return a 404 as well?
Should both methods be used to create a new object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, you will use either or both depending on whether or not you want the client (and therefore the user) to define the URI or not. If the client POSTs to `resources/` then the server gets to determine the URI for the resource. If the client PUTs to `resources/{id}/` then the client is determining the URI for the resource.

One exception is if creation involves links, states, and other items that are not then properly considered part of the resource--you generally cannot PUT these extra "constructor args" if you will, since they are not part of the resource state. Instead, you must POST in that case.

Even if you use POST for creation, you still might then want to expose PUT for updates. It depends on the resource.

If you don't allow a PUT to create then yes, you should return 404 in that situation.

Comment: I'm confused. Why should PUT update? You'll need the whole resource to update it using PUT, right? Saving all of the resource again is ineffecient (it might have a lot of data). It might make sense for a resources/{id}/{field}, but than what would POST do? I know that by convention POST updates and PUT replaces (therefor, if the resource is empty it creates one).

Comment: Yes, you will need the whole resource to update using PUT. It might seem inefficient, but is a critical part of what makes an application built using the REST architectural style scale to large deployments. You'll have to balance the size of your resources, or employ the PATCH method instead. PUT replaces--that's following the spec, not just convention. POST does "everything else", and is often used for updates.

Comment: I still don't get why should I allow PUT if POST can be used to update the resource.

Comment: Allowing a PUT lets the client declare their intent of a full replace, not a possibly-full-but-possibly-partial-update, and this uniform approach then allows other intermediaries to know that intent too. One of the things clients and intermediaries can do with that knowledge is retry failed requests safely, since PUT is idempotent. They cannot do that with POST, which is not. It may not be an obvious benefit in a small system, and therefore you don't have to use PUT, but in large systems, particularly big m2m ones, retrying failed requests safely can have a big impact on reliability.

Comment: @the_drow The POST is not idempotent, that is, multiple execution of POST with the same parameters produces new resources. Hence, it's against the standard to use it for updates (which must be idempotent). On the other hand, multiple PUTs must not create new resources, but instead perform "insert or update".